# Move group of elements up on keyboard enter in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, user-interface, android-constraintlayout

I'm currently trying to move a view previously done in `LinearLayout` to `ConstraintLayout`.

The trouble I'm facing is that I need to push a view up based on the keyboard. How to create a conditional chain?

This is how I'm making the constraints:

[image: constraints]

Normally I'd use `window:softInputMode` attribute set to `adjustResize` and my views work out fine. Even with that, in `ConstraintLayout` only the button is moving up since it has a constraint with parent's bottom.

I tried creating a biased constraint with some margin there from the `EditText` to the button. I cannot set the bias to anything other than zero, since otherwise it would move the edit text towards the button.

How should I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

Add Space view between your button and your EditText like below

```
<Space
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/yourButtonId"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/yourEditTextId" />
```